# Live streaming csv file in Power Bi report or dashboard

Tags: azure, csv, powerbi, live-streaming

I have a made a report in Power Bi that visualizes data imported from a csv file. The csv file contains fields from a Keras training process as well as fields on the current system usage statistics (CPU, RAM etc.). I have also successfully embedded the report.
However, the csv file gets new rows appended to it about every 5 minutes and I have to refresh the imported csv file manually so that the report is updated.

Is there a simple way for me to automate the process of refreshing the imported csv file when it is detected that the state of the file has changed?

I have been looking for a simple way to do this however I keep encountering Rest API's which I do not understand. Is it possible to use them with a csv file such that it updates every time the file changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use DirectQuery directly with CSV files. And if you want to get near realtime results in your report, importing (and refreshing) is not an option. Plus, there is a limit on the number of refreshes for a dataset (8 times a day for Pro, 48 times for Premium).

Your best option is to change the application to store this data in a [supported datasource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-directquery-data-sources) (or write a helper application to read the CSV and push the data to a supported datasource). If these rows are in Azure SQL Database for example, then you can create a dashboard that can [autorefresh itself every 15 minutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/refresh-data#types-of-refresh). If you need to refresh it more often, then you need to use a [streaming dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-real-time-streaming) (and again, find a way to push your data to it).